# JSTL - Promotional Code

Tags: jstl

I'm trying to use JSTL, so that if a user enters a code, it is looked up in the database, if it equals the value, then the following discount is applied.
I kind of have an idea/pseudocode of what i want to write but i cant get it working or where i should go from here

In my purchase page i have:

```
form action="promo.jsp" method="GET">
  Promotional Code: <input type="text" name="promo">
  <input type = "submit" id="promo" value = "Apply Code" />
</form>

<form action="complete_purchase.jsp" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" value="Complete Purchase" />
</form>
```

And in my "promo.jsp"
I have something a long the lines of:

```
<sql:query var="item">
select item_price from inventory; 
</sql:query>

<sql:query var="pro">
      select code,discount from promotion_code;
</sql:query>

<c:if test="${pro.promo eq 'spring01'}">
     <c:set var="user" value="${(item_price-(item_price*discount))}" scope="session"  />
</c:if>
<c:out value="${sessionScope.user}" />
```

So basically, when i click apply code, it stores the new value of the price in a variable, that i want to call on the "final purchase page"

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: If im heading in the right direction, and what parts seem wrong currently. Like how would I compare the input of a input form to a value in a database then store it in a variable to use on future pages

Comment: In my opinion, using the sql tag library is a complete no-no. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnald.html: *designed for quick prototyping and simple applications. For production applications, database operations are normally encapsulated in JavaBeans components*. So I would say that no, you're not heading in the right direction. Use Java code to implement your business and persistence logic. Use JSPs and the JSTL to generate HTML, from Java beans stored in attributes by a controller written in Java.